# Maximum number of services and/or characteristics in BlueNRG by STM

Tags: c++, c, bluetooth-lowenergy, stm32

I'm struggling with an issue regarding the number of GATT services, characteristics and descriptors in BlueNRG by STM.
I have currently set 6 services and 8 characteristics, minimizing the number of attributes for each service inside `maximum_attr_records` variable as input of GATT function `aci_gatt_add_serv()`.

Everything works fine until I add the seventh service or the nineth characteristic: the GAP does not initialize and the communication is stopped.

I imagined that is something connected to the number of attributes/services/characteristics used in my application that require all the GATT stack memory, but it seems weird.
Is there a way to increase this maximum value using the BlueNRG protocol?

BLE 4.1, STM32CUBEIDE 1.7.0, X-Cube-Ble 3.2.2

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt STM32CubeIde is a C/C++ platform. All the functions related to BlueNRG are written in C

Comment: Still, what is your question concerning those programming languages? Protocols, services and hardware are language-independent and the language of an IDE doesn't matter here either.

Comment: This sounds like a problem I had with the nRF52840 where I couldn't add more services. The problem was that the attribute table is of fixed size and the memory ran out. I increased the allocated size and also the memory region to work around this problem. Read [this](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/443/maximum-number-of-services) for more info. Maybe something like this works for you on the STM platform

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan thank you for your reply. However, I've already gone into that post but I can't find the correspondent variables/functions in ST repositories

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan Sorry if I bother you, could you please show me how did you increase the allocated GATT Memory in your device? Thanks in advance